# How do I change auto-formatting with the line breaks of after 'then' in RAD 10.4.2?

Tags: delphi, format, line-breaks

I'm using Rad Studio 10.4.2 Community.

The default auto-formatting of if statement is

```
if (statements) then
    Exit;
```

I've change some settings in Tools->Options->Language->Formatter->Delphi->Line Breaks to make a difference, and the result is

```
if (statements) 
then
    Exit;
```

What I want to do with auto-formatting is

```
if (statements) 
then Exit;
```

There is a setting option of "Line Breaks before Then" that can be changed.

but cannot find something like "Line Breaks after Then".

Is there any way to change that with auto-formatting?

Comment: Most probably you have to make feature request in Embarcadero Quality service (quality.embarcadero.com)

Comment: The real question is why you want to invent your own coding style and do not use the official coding style suggested by Embarcadero?

Comment: Because the company I work used to that style. and want to keep the style of it. I actually prefer the 'suggested by Embarcadero' style